# Regarding ערוך השלם

Tags: jewish-books

The ערוך השלם is a fantastic work and invaluable for learning Gemara. It was written by [Alexander (Chanoch Yehuda) Kohut](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Kohut) in the late 19th century. It is six volumes. It is available in those volumes on Hebrewbooks.org. [(E.g. Volume 1)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/48229)

To my knowledge, this work hasn’t been reprinted, if so, why?

Comment: Some of the works of the Vilna Gaon haven't even been reprinted. I think the book not being reprinted has nothing to do with the reputability of the work.

Comment: i think this is a legit. question about this sefer, if there is some info on it that would be interesting to shmuel. +1

Comment: I imagine Jastrow's dictionary's availability, especially it being in English, has  a lot to do with it; the coming of Artscroll is most likely also a factor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been reprinted a few times. The [NLI lists 6 editions](http://merhav.nli.org.il/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?ct=facet&fctN=facet_rtype&fctV=books&rfnGrp=2&rfnGrpCounter=2&dscnt=0&tab=default_tab&dstmp=1519073497225&srt=rank&ct=facet&mode=Basic&dum=true&indx=1&rfnIncGrp=1&rfnGrpCounter=1&mulIncFctN=facet_creator&vl(freeText0)=%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D&fn=search&fctIncV=%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C&vid=NLI) (of which one is the original so that makes 5 reprints. There's also one other book showing up in the linked search that you should ignore). I recently got rid of my copy, but it was a reprint from Pardes, a New York based publisher who made it in the 50s. Here's the title page:

[image: Aruch Hashalem from Pardes.]